# Access JSP variable from inside JSTL tag

Tags: jsp, variables, jstl

I am pretty new to Java and I am trying to figure out how to print variables inside a JSTL content section. I am not sure if I am doing this right but can't get it to work (actually it works with scriptlets).

So, here is the code:

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList,model.Livro,service.LivroService" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="t" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<% ArrayList<Livro> livros = LivroService.getAll(); %>

<t:admin>
    <jsp:attribute name="content">
        <h2 class="page-header">
            Livros cadastrados
            <span class="pull-right"><a href="criar.jsp" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Cadastrar livro</a></span>
        </h2>        

        <c:forEach var="livro" items="${livros}">
            <c:out value="${livro.titulo}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </jsp:attribute>
</t:admin>
```

When compiling I get errors like this:

> /home/raphael/NetBeansProjects/LingProg/build/generated/src/org/apache/jsp/admin/livro/index_jsp.java:105:
>   error: package org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core does not exist
>       org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag _jspx_th_c_forEach_0 = (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag)
>   _jspx_tagPool_c_forEach_var_items.get(org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag.class);

I am not sure what's going on. Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you include jstl jar in classpath?

Comment: Yes, it has been done.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue would lie with the [JSTL jar](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) not being included in your classpath, but that has been addressed in the comments.

Since you are retrieving a list of objects through a static service method, I would recommend refactoring this to the backend like so:

```
request.setAttribute("livros", LivroService.getAll());
```

The reason for this is that the expression engine attempts to resolve variables through the attribute mappings of the `PageContext`, the`Request`, the `Session`, and the `Servlet Context` - in that order. Scriptlets are raw Java statements on the page and will not be resolved if referenced in an expression.

If you refactor the code as suggested, `${ livros }` will be resolved as you intended as it has been added as an attribute to the request.